# left join explanation from sqlzoo #13

Tags: sql, left-join

Can someone explain me why left join is needed to get all the results?
If I'm using a simple join it will ignore the matches where no goals had been scored (0-0) and I don't understand why (because it is a sum function)

```
SELECT mdate,team1,
SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1 , team2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2 
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON (id = matchid)
GROUP BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: Hard to be sure as you haven't fully qualified your column names (meaning it's difficult to know which table each column comes from). However, it seems that, if no goals had been scored, no records will be in the goal table. An inner join (your "simple join") will only show records that exist in both tables. So only those games where a goal is scored. A left join will show all records that exist in the left table (game), regardless of their not being a matching record in the right (goal).

Comment: Without seeing your data we can only assume that there were ganes without goals. You need an outer join to show any games that do not have at least one goal record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a left join, then every GAME record is included in your result set, regardless of whether a GOAL record is present or not.

If you use an inner join, then only GAMEs where a GOAL record can be found are included (and only GOALs belonging to an existing GAME are included).  If a game has no goals, it will not be included.

(After you have built up this record set, you then do the GROUP BY and generate SUM values, but that process is not relevant to the join results.)

Comment: the tables are game(id, mdate, stadium, team1, team2) goal(matchid,teamid,player,goaltime).  ok, but the question is if i am defying a case thats mean i gave a value even if its 0 no?

Comment: But it isn't zero, it's NULL, because the record doesn't exist.